# Redirect old homepage to the new one within the same site

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I am wondering how can I redirect the old homepage

`https://blog.example.com/` to the new one `https://www.example.com/ratgeber/`

I have tried to redirect it via a WordPress Plugin, but when I insert the origin URL and the target URL I am getting the error message "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" .. for a better understanding of the issue you can take a look at the extract from a status-code-checker. I do not know how to solve this loop.

[image]

Could please someone tell me the correct syntax to put in the `.htaccess`? Hereby you can see all the directives included at the present moment in this file. The very first two lines of code are unfortunately not working as desired.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.(terminsvertreter\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1/ratgeber%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://www.terminsvertreter.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# Die Anweisungen (Zeilen) zwischen `BEGIN WordPress` und `END WordPress` sind
# dynamisch generiert und sollten nur über WordPress-Filter geändert werden.
# Alle Änderungen an den Anweisungen zwischen diesen Markierungen werden überschrieben.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are you literally only redirecting the "homepage"? My answer assumes any URL, eg. `https://blog.example.com/<anything>`.

Comment: I updated the body of the question including the code snippet you suggested. I literally want to redirect only the old homepage to the new one, since there are no other https://blog URLs left.

Comment: You are missing a _space_ after the `^` (first argument). (Curious that you just edited the question to remove that space?!) Your later HTTP to HTTPS redirect should not include `/ratgeber` in the _substitution_ string, the _pattern_ should be `^`, not `.`, and this rule should also be outside of the WordPress code block, after the first rule.

Comment: Dear @MrWhite, I am bound to state that I know very little about redirect rules. Anyway, I updated the .htaccess file according to your latest suggestions. Unfortunately, https://blog.example.com/ is still NOT redirecting to https://www.example.com/ratgeber/ .. could you please kindly take a second look?

Comment: You appear to be missing the `RewriteEngine On` directive?! By default this would be present in the the WordPress code block, immediately before the `RewriteBase` directive (unless it has been explicitly removed). Logically, this should be at the top of file, but it doesn't actually matter where it goes. (If it was present in the original WP code block then it should not be moved.) Failure to enable the rewrite engine _somewhere_ (ie. with `RewriteEngine On`) will effectively disable all the mod_rewrite directives in the `.htaccess` file!

Comment: Just to add... If you only have a homepage and no other "pages" then you wouldn't necessarily notice that the `.htaccess` file wasn't actually doing anything, since it's not required for requests to the homepage.

Comment: Just added the RewriteEngine On directive. Nothing changed, the redirect is still not working. We do have a homepage and other pages, the issue is that the homepage is available under two different URLs. There are no other https://blog.example.com/ pages available, apart from the aforementioned homepage.

Comment: According to a DNS lookup of the `blog.example.com` and `www.example.com` hostnames they appear to resolve to different servers (different IP addresses)?!

Comment: Dear @MrWhite, does it mean that I should go after the .htaccess file of blog.example.com instead of the one of www.example.com/ratgeber/ one? I just took a look in the plesk panel. There are no two separate entities named blog.example.com and www.example.com. The wp-login of blog.example.com redirects to www.example.com, as any other page of blog.example.com. Only the old blog.example.com homepage is left :/is still irreducibly present online

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the `blog` subdomain would point to a different filesystem location (its own document root), then you could use a simple `Redirect` directive in its own `.htaccess` file in the root of the subdomain. For example:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/ratgeber/
```

The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target, so `https://blog.example.com/anything` is redirected to `https://www.example.com/ratgeber/anything`.

However, if both hostnames point to the same place (as would seem to be the case) then you will need to use mod_rewrite at the very top of the root `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1/ratgeber%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This specifically checks for the `blog.example.com` hostname in the preceding *condition*. The `%1` backreference simply saves repetition having captured the domain name in the preceding *condition*.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable already contains the slash prefix.

Always test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. You should clear your browser cache before testing.

---

If you aren't serving multiple domains (that could also have a `blog` subdomain) then you can make the rule entirely generic (to avoid hardcoding the domain name), to redirect from the `blog` subdomain to `www` (plus subdirectory). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
:
```

Comment: Dear @MrWhite, thank you very much for sharing your expertise. The very simple Redirect 301 originates a redirect loop. It looks like both hostnames point to the same place as you suggested. Hereby you can find the entire set of rules included in the .htaccess. I guess that we are close to the solution, but the "hack" you suggested is not working yet :/

Comment: @RomanTrushanov Can you please update/edit your question in order to retain the formatting of the code. Thanks. The unformatted code in the comment looks like it is missing some bits (but this might be due to the unformatted code, which can omit certain characters). However, the redirect in my answer needs to go at the very top of the `.htaccess` file (literally), outside of the WordPress code block, _before_ the `<IfModule>` directive and _before_ the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.